# Android - Pairing dialog does not appear

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I noticed that sometimes when I pair with a BLE device with my phone which is a central device in this case and the BLE device is a sensor which is acting like a peripheral. There are rare instances where I see that no pairing dialog appears on the Android phone asking the user to pair, and that it just pairs successfully by itself. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Do you mean pair or connect? Devices can communicate without being paired, although unencrypted.

Comment: @Emil I don't have a BLE sniffer, but from what I see with my callbacks, the bond status is BONDED, which means authentication and key exchange succeeded at least.

Comment: What Android version do you have?

Comment: Samsung Android 10